# How to expand the C\C++ macro in Rust to remove redundant code

Tags: c++, rust

I have a this code in C++ which is expanding some const code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct ObjAttribution {
    std::string id;
    struct attribute {
        std::string file_name;
        int code;
        std::string companion_name;
        attribute(std::string f, int c, std::string cn) : file_name(f), code(c), companion_name(cn) {}
    } attribute_type;
    ObjAttribution(std::string i, std::string f, int c, std::string cn)
    : id(i)
    , attribute_type(f, c, cn) {}
};

#define CONST_ATTRIBUTE(id, x, y, z) const ObjAttribution id(#id, #x, y, #z);
#define _x_(id, x, y, z) CONST_ATTRIBUTE(id, x, y, z)

// this will be great if I can convert something similar to this in rust - internally it should be creating const global object
_x_(USER_IO, user_info.txt, 64, user_companion.txt)  
_x_(USER_IO_1, user_info_1.txt, 65, user_companion_1.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_2, user_info_2.txt, 66, user_companion_2.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_3, user_info_3.txt, 67, user_companion_3.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_4, user_info_4.txt, 68, user_companion_4.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_5, user_info_5.txt, 69, user_companion_5.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_6, user_info_6.txt, 70, user_companion_6.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_7, user_info_7.txt, 71, user_companion_7.txt)
_x_(USER_IO_8, user_info_8.txt, 72, user_companion_8.txt)

int main() {

    std::cout << USER_IO_1.id << " --> " << USER_IO_1.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_1.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_1.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";
    std::cout << USER_IO_2.id << " --> " << USER_IO_2.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_2.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_2.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";
    std::cout << USER_IO_3.id << " --> " << USER_IO_3.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_3.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_3.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";
    std::cout << USER_IO_4.id << " --> " << USER_IO_4.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_4.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_4.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";
    std::cout << USER_IO_5.id << " --> " << USER_IO_5.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_5.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_5.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";
    std::cout << USER_IO_6.id << " --> " << USER_IO_6.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_6.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_6.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";
    std::cout << USER_IO_7.id << " --> " << USER_IO_7.attribute_type.file_name << " --> " << USER_IO_7.attribute_type.code <<  " --> " << USER_IO_7.attribute_type.companion_name << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering how can I convert that in Rust. I want to do the processing in the compile time rather than in the runtime. I want to make it deliberate to reader to get the attributes that expands in the same way, but without the need to declare them explicitly as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you can accept quoting the names:

```rust
struct Attribute {
    file_name: &'static str,
    code: i32,
    companion_name: &'static str,
}
struct ObjAttribution {
    id: &'static str,
    attribute_type: Attribute,
}
impl ObjAttribution {
    const fn new(id: &'static str, file_name: &'static str, code: i32, companion_name: &'static str) -> Self {
        ObjAttribution {
            id,
            attribute_type: Attribute {
                file_name,
                code,
                companion_name,
            },
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! x {
    ($id:ident, $x:literal, $y:literal, $z:literal) => {
        const $id: ObjAttribution = ObjAttribution::new(stringify!($id), $x, $y, $z);
    };
}

x!(USER_IO, "user_info.txt", 64, "user_companion.txt");
x!(USER_IO_1, "user_info_1.txt", 65, "user_companion_1.txt");
x!(USER_IO_2, "user_info_2.txt", 66, "user_companion_2.txt");
x!(USER_IO_3, "user_info_3.txt", 67, "user_companion_3.txt");
x!(USER_IO_4, "user_info_4.txt", 68, "user_companion_4.txt");
x!(USER_IO_5, "user_info_5.txt", 69, "user_companion_5.txt");
x!(USER_IO_6, "user_info_6.txt", 70, "user_companion_6.txt");
x!(USER_IO_7, "user_info_7.txt", 71, "user_companion_7.txt");
x!(USER_IO_8, "user_info_8.txt", 72, "user_companion_8.txt");

fn main() {
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_1.id, USER_IO_1.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_1.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_1.attribute_type.companion_name);
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_2.id, USER_IO_2.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_2.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_2.attribute_type.companion_name);
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_3.id, USER_IO_3.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_3.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_3.attribute_type.companion_name);
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_4.id, USER_IO_4.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_4.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_4.attribute_type.companion_name);
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_5.id, USER_IO_5.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_5.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_5.attribute_type.companion_name);
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_6.id, USER_IO_6.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_6.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_6.attribute_type.companion_name);
    println!("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}", USER_IO_7.id, USER_IO_7.attribute_type.file_name, USER_IO_7.attribute_type.code, USER_IO_7.attribute_type.companion_name);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7725a79a880020d296851e2e6e1347d2)

It's probably possible to avoid quoting the strings, but would make the macro drastically more complex.

Note: I used `&'static str` because Rust doesn't allow creating `String`s (except empty ones) in constant contexts. If you want to use `ObjAttribution` in both const and non-const contexts, you'll probably have to switch to `Cow<'static, str>`.